# AJAX: Getting the metadata like, meta description, of the loaded html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello with code below i can parse title of a request web page:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        var title = data.match("<title>(.*?)</title>")[1];
        console.log(title);

    },
    fail: function () {
        console.log("Encountered an error")
    }
 });
```

Now i need help to know how extract METATAG from page, like meta description, author and more, any help about? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User jQuery filter option and extract from Ajax response-

```
success : function (data) {
   var mdesc = $(data).filter('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
   var mauthor = $(data).filter('meta[name="author"]').attr("content");
   var mkeywords = $(data).filter('meta[name="keywords"]').attr("content");
}
```